# PAC-learning framework: Why the sample size must also be polynomial if the full sample is received by the algorithm

Tags: machine-learning

On page 11 in the book *Foundation of Machine Learning*, 2nd edition MIT press, the authors wrote:

> Definition 2.3 (PAC-learning) A concept class $C$ is said to be PAC-learnable if there exists an algorithm $A$ and a polynomial function $poly(·,·,·,·)$ such that for any $ε > 0$ and $δ > 0$, for all distributions $D$ on $X$ and for any target concept $c ∈ C$, the following holds for any sample size m ≥ poly(1/ε, 1/δ, n, size(c)):
> $P[R(h_{S}) \le \epsilon] \ge 1−\delta$, $S\sim D_{m}$. (2.4)

The authors further explained:

> If A further runs in $poly(1/ε, 1/δ, n, size(c))$, then C is said to be efficiently PAC- learnable. When such an algorithm A exists, it is called a PAC-learning algorithm for C.
>
> A concept class *C* is thus PAC-learnable if the hypothesis returned by the algorithm after observing a number of points polynomial in $1/ε$ and $1/δ$ is approximately correct (error at most ε) with high probability (at least 1 − δ), which justifies the PAC terminology. The parameter δ > 0 is used to define the confidence 1 − δ and ε > 0 the accuracy 1 − ε.

Which I can understand. However, I couldn't understand when they wrote:

> Note that if the running time of the algorithm is polynomial in 1/ε and 1/δ, then the sample size m must also be polynomial if the full sample is received by the algorithm.

Could anyone help to explain why the sample size m must also be polynomial if the full sample is received by the algorithm if the running time is polynomial in 1/ε and 1/δ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption is that the algorithm must read in data (given that the full sample is received) thus it is $\Omega(m)$. So, if $m$ is not polynomial, there is no way for the algorithm to be polytime as well.